# VLAN and DHCP problems

Tags: dhcp, vlan

Ok, so in my wonderful world of subnets and vlans and all, I just thought I'd collapse down what I didn't need as a VLAN for printers and one for clients (learning stuff) and decided to keep everything on VLAN 1 (or untagged in this case) for clients, servers and printers.

Basically I created myself now a 192.168.0.1/22 range, which should give me a usable range between 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.3.254 with a 255.255.252.0 subnet mask and a gateway of 192.168.0.1 .

Now, I'm setting up DHCP again to start serving up some addresses, as it was just doing 192.168.1.50 to 254 .

Now, I'd like it to serve up 192.168.3.2 through 254. However...I can't seem to get it to do it.

I've tried Windows DHCP (where it was all running before) and the Meraki MX64's DHCP servers which also don't seem to serve it up either.

What in the hell am I do wrong? I'm re-reading all the dummies guides and again, I thought I had it all figured out correctly, and yet here I am!

Would appreciate a sanity check, and don't feel bad for an ELI5 approach, I may need it in my fog right now.

Comment: This sounds like a Server Admin type of question, but maybe it is not too complicated for here. https://serverfault.com

Comment: show us your DHCP pool configuration.

Comment: They will not allow this question on ServerFault since he said it's for a home lab ("learning stuff"). Not happy about it, but it's how the site is run.

Comment: Re: "Windows DHCP (where it was all running before)" So, let's think about what changed...adding the VLAN, the IP scheme...both? Important to remember that a VLAN is no different from a physical LAN, really. I would start by removing the VLAN but keeping the IP scheme at 192.168.1.0/22. If it works (I have my doubts) you know it's the VLAN. If not, troubleshoot the DHCP server.

Comment: You're gonna have to disclose more detail regardless for an accurate answer. Yes, sure someone may have a lucky guess that works to resolve the problem but if you want answers with some accuracy, consider adding more detail—DHCP configurations sound like a good starting point. What are you defining the VLANs on exactly and what do those configs look like? You need it to serve up a `192.168.3.X` so your DHCP configs from the Windows Server should suffice and I would just use Windows for DHCP since that's what you were using in the past before the change.